# disabling ipad from creating placemarks on google map

Tags: ios, ipad, google-maps, kml

I have a google map that I created with KML:

[image]

Here is a link to the map:

http://goo.gl/maps/dkfjU

Here is the complete KML file:

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/94943007/02bb39645a3c9d95afeed5cb9bd5d07c040d8ca8a4ee56b9fb367d38.kml

When browsing this map with my IPAD **using safari**, for some reason when I tap anywhere on the map, it creates a point there on the map.

**How do I disable point creation on the map so that IPAD users are not able to do this?**

Comment: @DonamiteIsTnt that made me blush

Comment: Your link simply points to maps.google.com, which is not a site you control, so there's nothing you can do about it. If it was you own application then that would be a different story.

Comment: @Marcelo im not sure how familiar you are with KML, but it is in fact the KML file that controls the behavior

Comment: How do you browse it on your iPad? Safari? UIWebView?

Comment: @user1071136 i browse it on safari

Comment: If you're viewing simple Google Maps, without the KML file, I guess it's working properly?

Comment: @user1071136 yes but it shouldnt be adding placemarks

Comment: your kml file is no longer on dropbox, can you please make sure it's there again so i can look into this issue?

Comment: @SuviVignarajah i just restored it! thank you for letting me know

Comment: @SuviVignarajah any updates on this? do you need my help in understanding anything?

Comment: I am somehow not able to reproduce this. On iOS 5 on an iPad 1st gen.

Comment: @n9986 thanks so much for trying. when you browse to the link and you tap anywhere, red placemarks arent automatically created?

Comment: I tried again. But am just not able to create any place marks simply by tapping. Double taps causes a zoom in. Maybe some version difference? Or gesture difference? It does happen if I click some monument/institute/defined location. But not at random places. Are these the ones you pointing to?

Comment: For me, it doesn't create a placemark when I tap on the map.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this condition on my side(iPad1 iOS5.1.1, iPad1 iOS5.1).. have you tested this condition on other devices

Answer (score 2):

I checked the link as well and Marcelo seems to be correct. To have a maps with the ability to turn on and off layers you will need to build your own site and perhaps use Javascript and the Google-maps API to build it. Maybe start here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Comment: thanks so much can you please show me how using javascript i can disable this functionality

Comment: The functionality will not be **enabled** if you build your own website. 
If you want a simple map , without the ability to turn on and off layers) , without having to learn Javascript or paying for your own website maybe try creating one in Weebly. There are some good instructions on how to add a map to a Weebly website here: https://sites.google.com/site/sitetemplateinfo/tips/replace-a-map.

Answer (score 2):

**You cannot disable adding a place mark if you are browsing the map in safari**

You **can control** it if you use map kit iOS API of the iOS SDK.

- For importing KML-Data into that SDK, you can use Sample Code from
  Apple:
  http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/KMLViewer/Introduction/Intro.html
- But there is no built-in KML Import in iOS SDK. You can use other
  frameworks as mapbox/Simple-KML here
  https://github.com/mapbox/Simple-KML

If you want to do this in safari, then you're lost, unless you can **manipulate that using JavaScript!!!**

Comment: thank you so much. can you please direct me on how i can try to manipulate that using javascript??